# Is there an example for a simple Nodejs/Mongoose application?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I start coding a simple Nodejs and Mongoose based application? Here is the simple TCP server:

```javascript
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    //here I want to save data.toString() in a simple db
    //db is yet not created, shld I create it first manually?
    //data format is {_id : 'automatically generated', rawValue: 'data.toString()'}
  });
});

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using mongoose, it will look something like the following:

```
var   sys       = require('util')
    , mongoose  = require('mongoose');

//setup mongose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DataSchema = new Schema({
    rawValue: String
});

mongoose.model('data', DataSchema);

var net = require('net');

    var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
      socket.on('data', function(data){
        var Data = mongoose.model('data');
        var object = new Data();
        object.rawValue = data;
        object.save();
        console.log('Saved object');
      });
    });

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```